# Sorting algorithm gives wrong results

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c[5], d;

    cout << "enter any five number\n";
    for(a=0; a<5; a++)
    {
        cin>>c[a];
    }
    for(a=0; a<5; a++)
    {
        for(b=++a; b<5; b++)
        {
            if(c[b] < c[a])
            {
                d = c[b];
                c[b] = c[a];
                c[a] = d;
            }
        }       
    }

    cout << "\nhere is the entered numbers in order\n"; 
    for(a=0; a<5; a++)
    {
        cout << c[a];
        cout << endl;
    }
    getch();
    return 3;
}
```

I am desk checking this program and I expect the program to sort numbers in ascending order but I am getting the wrong output help please.

Comment: no,no no @MarounMaroun i am sorry, if it's a bad habit this is my last time.

Comment: Could you not just use std::sort?

Comment: @Ralara: the original format of the title really suggested that this is a task assigned as an excercise

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a transcript of your desk-check, so that we could help you figure out where exactly your program's behavior differs from what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the inner loop it should be `a + 1` not `++a`

Answer (score 1):

`for(a=0;a<5;a++)` and `for(b=++a;..)` causes `a` to be incremented twice.

Did you mean `for(b=a+1;b<5;b++)` ?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant but i did not know that the second loop is the one causing that output, thank you so much @quetzalcoatl

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(a=0; a<5; a++)
    {
        for(b=++a; b<5; b++)
        {
            if(c[b] < c[a])
            {
                d = c[b];
                c[b] = c[a];
                c[a] = d;
            }
        }       
    }
```

this should be

```
for(a=0; a<4; a++)
{
    for(b=a+1; b<5; b++)
    {
        if(c[b] < c[a])
        {
            d = c[b];
            c[b] = c[a];
            c[a] = d;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: a<4 should be better to avoid a useless step.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(a=0; a<5-1; a++){
  for(b=0; b<5-a-1; b++){
    if(c[b] < c[a]){
      d = c[b];
      c[b] = c[a];
      c[a] = d;
    }
  }
}
```